# Bundler cannot find platform specific gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am completely new to Ruby and tasked to revive an old Ruby project. I tried looking at a Gem file and removed all version restrictions from it. When I do `bundler install` the first problem I run into was

```
Could not find gem 'rails x86_64-linux' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I was able to

```
gem install rails
```

Just fine, so why is bundler trying to get `rails x86_64-linux`? How can I avoid that?

Thanks

Comment: whats in your gemfile? bundler version? ruby version? are you on linux? "old Ruby project" - how old is that? there have been an incredible amount of changes in ruby from v1 to v2 to v3. "rails x86_64-linux" is not a valid gem name, could be just a syntax issue.

Comment: What does your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was asked above, depending on how old are things and what's your goal (for instance, migrate to newer versions of things), you may want to do it gradually.
In that sense, you could try to isolate the "old" architecture in a Docker image (see [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/rails/)) and try to modify small things from there.

In a Docker container, you'll be able to use the "old" architecture, prepare version changes gradually and test the system locally.